# Python OpenCV: Rotating/moving 2D image in 3D space, saving 2D image of camera view

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, 3d, transformation

I'd like to have a Python function (using OpenCV and Numpy) which takes

- a 2D image (height x width uint8 numpy array = OpenCV grayscale image)
- information on where the image is relative to the camera (let's say it's at the origin of a cartesian coordinate system)
- how the image is turned in 3D space

and returns

- a 2D grayscale image of what the camera sees

Why I need this:
I'm trying to find a 2D-rectangle-shaped object with a pattern on it in a real photo and want to know (I know how big it is) it's position relative to the camera. My approach is to (smartly) guess the position/rotation and then compute a score for how well it fits.

Comment: so you need to draw a texture on a quad? sounds like you want OpenGL/Direct3D or something more user-friendly -- or do you want to learn about homographies and 4x4 pose/transformation matrices?

Comment: Texture on a quad will work (OpenGL or maybe Open3D?). You can also use openCVs projectPoints on 4 image points and "render" the image with homography image warping.

Comment: Either one will do, I study Computer Science in a math-heavy way.

Comment: I thought about taking the 2D rectangle and moving/rotating it in 3D space. I only need to know where a pixel in that 2D rectangle would end up after certain moves/rotations or alternatively the other way around = knowing where a pixel the "camera" sees is on the rectangle.